# 'service discovery failed' error in bluetooth chat application while trying to connect with a remote device, which is not available at that time

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

i am building a bluetooth chat application in android platform. everything is going fine but i have slight bug in my application . when i am trying to connect with a remote device which is present in my paired devices list and not available currently as a nearby device, then it throws "service discovery failed" exception and my application gets terminated automatically .
     To prevent this automatic termination i have also put the condition like if such a exception occurs then start the "accept thread" again but it is not working.

mainActivity.java source code

package simpleweather.bluetooth_test1;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Set;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private UUID myUUID;
    private String myName;
    Button Refresh;
    ListView NewDevices;
    ArrayList<String> ScanNewList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> ScanNewAdapter;
    server serverconnection=null;
    ArrayList<String> conversation;
    ArrayAdapter<String>  sessionchat;
    ListView MsgList;
    ArrayList<String> pairedDeviceArrayList;
    ListView listViewPairedDevice;
    ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDeviceAdapter;
    client clientconnection=null;
    communication datatransfer=null;
    EditText input;
    FloatingActionButton sent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NewDevices=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.newDevices);
        ScanNewList=new ArrayList<String>();
        Refresh=(Button)findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        ScanNewAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ScanNewList);
        NewDevices.setAdapter(ScanNewAdapter);
        sent=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.send);
        input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
        MsgList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.msglist);
        conversation=new ArrayList<String>();
        sessionchat = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, conversation);
        MsgList.setAdapter(sessionchat);
        TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec=tabHost.newTabSpec("paireddevices");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.pairedDevices);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Paired Devices");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        tabSpec=tabHost.newTabSpec("msgArea");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.chatArea);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Start Chat");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        tabSpec=tabHost.newTabSpec("newdiscovered_devices");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.newdevices);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Scan Devices");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        listViewPairedDevice=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        sent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(datatransfer!=null){
                    byte[] bytesToSend = input.getText().toString().getBytes();
                    datatransfer.write(bytesToSend,input.getText().toString());
                    input.setText("");
                }
            }});
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH)){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"FEATURE_BLUETOOTH NOT support",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        myUUID = UUID.fromString("ec79da00-853f-11e4-b4a9-0800200c9a66");
        myName = myUUID.toString();
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Bluetooth is not supported on this hardware platform",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }else{
            server_start();
            client_start();
        }

        Refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        });
         // start discovery for new devices
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND); // registering broadcast reciever for retrieving information of new devices
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        NewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { // list of newly scaned devices
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
                BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Name: " + device.getName() + "\n" + "Address: " + device.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                clientconnection = new client(device);
                clientconnection.start();

            }
        });

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 1
        if(requestCode==1) {
           Log.d("Shashank","Bluetooth turned on ");
            server_start();
            client_start();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void server_start() {
        if(clientconnection!=null)
        {
            clientconnection.cancel();
            clientconnection=null;
        }
        if(datatransfer!=null){
            datatransfer.cancel();
            datatransfer=null;
        }
        if(serverconnection!=null) {
            serverconnection.cancel();
            serverconnection = null;
        }
        serverconnection = new server();
            serverconnection.start();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        if(bluetoothAdapter!=null){
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        if(serverconnection!=null){
            serverconnection.cancel();
            serverconnection=null;
        }
        if(clientconnection!=null){
            clientconnection.cancel();
            clientconnection=null;
        }

    }
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if(!ScanNewList.contains(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress())) {
                    ScanNewList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    ScanNewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        }
    };

    private class server extends Thread {
        private BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothServerSocket = null;
        public server() {
            try {
                bluetoothServerSocket = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(myName, myUUID);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Waiting\n" + "bluetoothServerSocket :\n" + bluetoothServerSocket,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                server_start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
            if(bluetoothServerSocket!=null){
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();
                    BluetoothDevice remoteDevice = bluetoothSocket.getRemoteDevice();
                    final String strConnected = "Connected:\n" + remoteDevice.getName() + "\n" +remoteDevice.getAddress();

                    //connected
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),strConnected,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }});
                    start_communication(bluetoothSocket,remoteDevice.getName());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    final String eMessage = e.getMessage();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"something wrong: \n" + eMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }});
                    server_start();
                }
            }else{
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"bluetoothServerSocket == null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }});
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"close bluetoothServerSocket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                bluetoothServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private void client_start() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.listView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pairedDeviceArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            pairedDeviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pairedDeviceArrayList);
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                pairedDeviceArrayList.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());

            }
            pairedDeviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listViewPairedDevice.setAdapter(pairedDeviceAdapter);
            listViewPairedDevice.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                    String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
                    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Name: " + device.getName() + "\n"+ "Address: " + device.getAddress(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    clientconnection = new client(device);
                    clientconnection.start();
                }});
        }
    }
    private class client extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
        private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

        public client(BluetoothDevice device) {
            bluetoothDevice = device;
            try {
                bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"bluetoothSocket: \n" + bluetoothSocket,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
                server_start();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean success = false;
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                success = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                final String eMessage = e.getMessage();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"something wrong bluetoothSocket.connect(): \n" + eMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }});

                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e2){
                  e2.printStackTrace();
                    server_start();
                }


            }
            if(success){
                //connect successful
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"connection successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }});
                start_communication(bluetoothSocket,bluetoothDevice.getName());
            }else{
                //fail
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Could not connected with the device!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                server_start();
            }
        }
        public void cancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Closed bluetoothSocket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    private void start_communication(BluetoothSocket socket,String chater){

        datatransfer = new communication(socket,chater);
        datatransfer.start();
    }
    private class communication extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket connectedBluetoothSocket;
        private final InputStream connectedInputStream;
        private final OutputStream connectedOutputStream;
        String deviceName;
        public communication(BluetoothSocket socket,String chater) {
            connectedBluetoothSocket = socket;
            deviceName=chater;
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = socket.getInputStream();
                out = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connectedInputStream = in;
            connectedOutputStream = out;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                    String strReceived = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    final String msgReceived =strReceived;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            conversation.add(deviceName+" : "+msgReceived);
                            sessionchat.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }});

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    final String msgConnectionLost = "Connection lost:\n" + e.getMessage();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msgConnectionLost, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            server_start();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void write(byte[] buffer,String sendmsg) {
            try {
                connectedOutputStream.write(buffer);
                conversation.add("Me : "+sendmsg);
                sessionchat.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                server_start();
            }
        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                connectedBluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and this is activity layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="simpleweather.bluetooth_test1.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


        <TabHost
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tabHost"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="340dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="392dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/chatArea"
                        android:layout_width="361dp"
                        android:layout_height="541dp"
                        android:weightSum="1">
                        <ListView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="380dp"
                            android:id="@+id/msglist"
                            android:stackFromBottom="true"
                            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
                            android:layout_weight="0.87"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/send" />
                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="230dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/input"
                            android:hint="Type Message"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send"
                            android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

                        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                            android:id="@+id/send"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/input"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/newdevices"
                        android:layout_width="355dp"
                        android:layout_height="516dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Refresh Scan"
                            android:id="@+id/refresh"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                        <ListView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="379dp"
                            android:id="@+id/newDevices"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.47" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/pairedDevices"
                        android:layout_width="374dp"
                        android:layout_height="500dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:text="Tap over the Listed Devices to start Connection"
                            android:id="@+id/textView"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:text="Paired Devices"
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                        <ListView
                            android:layout_width="350dp"
                            android:layout_height="450dp"
                            android:id="@+id/listView"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
                            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i have screenshot showing the bug . 
[screenshot showing the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYplN.png)

I am confused why all this happening . I searched for the similar questions but i didn't found the situation like my bug . Please help me .

Comment: plzzz someone help me.... :-(

Comment: post the logcat log when the error appears.

Comment: You might want to look into the error path:
  }else{
         //fail
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Could not connected with the device!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                server_start();
            }

Comment: Mahendran Sakkarai ... i tried a lot to debug this problem by looking at the logcat and using some checkpoints to capture the bug ...but everytime i found that when "Service discovery failed " my code is running befor  the condition If(success==true) that it...

Comment: thats why i tried to start the Server_start() again in the else part of if condition

Comment: #Holger sorry but did'nt get hint...

Comment: should i post the complete code and layout files so that you guys can check it on your device and figure it out ???

Comment: i have posted the logcat log when the error appears @MahendranSakkarai

Comment: I haven't seen any error message like you mentioned above "service discovery failed". You will get which line you are getting the error in logcat. check @Holger answer which place give the error.

Comment: i am posting complete source code please try it once ....

Answer (score 0):

I meant that if your connection failed with an exception, then the error path is executed.
The code to show the "Toast" in the error path is different from all the other Toast calls. (ie. its probably not called on the UI thread), so that might be the issue. 
Or there might be an issue somewhere within the server.start() call.

Comment: yupp you are right  #Holger i was also thinking about that issue ...tried to resolve it but did not get successeded ....

Comment: now i am again editing my post and posting my complete project source code .... so please try it and let me know how to resolve the bug which i am getting ...please help me to resolve it

Comment: The new code still shows the failure toast on the background thread. Also I noticed that if the server thread fails to accept the server socket it will start itself again, which will probably lead to an stack overflow.

Comment: how can i resolve this problem ....please tell me where should i implement the changes and what they are ??